# Is it permissible to work in a bank in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, banking

I want to know if working in a bank is Haram or Halal in Islam? I am currently working in a Investment company. I am getting confused regarding this ruling.

Answer (score 3):

Banks serve a very important function in current society. Unfortunately,  one of those activities also includes dealing with interest. But, leaving that aside,  most of the halal businesses would not be able to function without the access to funds, and the facilitation of transactions.

So, as a blanket statement, Banks are not haram, and working at a bank should not be Haram.

That being said, dealing with credit cards, interest based loans, highly leveraged trading, most derivative financial products, these are in the gray area. Some worse than others.

If all you care about is making money, I'm sure there's other careers that will pay to keep you satisfied with your life.

If you want to redefine finance, and make it more islamic, a bank job is a good place to learn what's broken. But, be realistic about it. It's easier said than done. But, it is better to try than to give up.

If you are passionate about banking, then the responsibility is on you to make sure you handle the gray areas. It is not easy to do though.

FYI. This is my personal opinion based on industry knowledge.

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam SE. Please consider taking your time and take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about this site.